# How can i have different home page in different languages in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

is it possible to have  in one language (greek) a front page that displays my latest posts and a static page (english) in wordpress?

And how with the plugin wpml?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It`s possible.
I recomend use WPML plugin ( comercial) 
U also can use noncomercional plugins like:

- qTranslate
- Polylang